# How to type an asynchronous potentially process-exiting function in typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types

How do I type an asynchronous function that sometimes exits the process?
I want to be able to use it like this:

```js
function useResult(result:Result): void {
    // ...
}

const result: Result | undefined = await getResult();
if (result === undefined) reportError({ fatal: true });
useResult(result) // I want the type of result to be `Result` here, not `Result | undefined`

const result: Result | undefined = await getResult();
if (result === undefined) reportError({ fatal: false });
useResult(result) // I want the type of result to be `Result | undefined` here
```

Here's the function in question:

```js
import { exit } from "node:process";

interface ReportableError {
    fatal?: true | false | undefined;
    // ...
}

export async function reportError<E extends ReportableError>(
    e: E,
) { // <-- How do I type the return of this function?

    // Log the error, do some async stuff...

    if (e.fatal) {
        // Stop running
        exit();
    }
    // Continue running
}
```

Comment: Does "exit the process" mean something node-specific?  If so then you might want to tag it as such.  But if a function never actually returns (due to an exception or other world-ending event) then the return type is [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never). Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wXKpVW) meet your needs?  If so I could write up an answer (although you might want to [edit] your code to use my standalone example instead of `exit()`. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, exiting the process is node-specific and that approach meets my needs. Also, the return type of exit() from `node:process` is `never`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way this will work is if you make `reportError()` an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) with separate call signatures for the "fatal" and "non-fatal" varieties of input.

---

Essentially you want `reportError({fatal: true})` to return [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#never) because the function will never return.  When you call a function whose call signature's return type is just `never`, the compiler can use [control flow analysis](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) to narrow the types of variables based on reachability of code. This was implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#32695](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/32695), and only triggers if the return type is explicitly annotated as just `never`.

Since you want

```
if (result === undefined) reportError({ fatal: true });
```

to narrow `result` from `Result | undefined` to `Result`, that means `reportError()` must return a `never`.  So one call signature of `reportError` should look like

```
function reportError(e: { fatal: true }): never;
```

Note that we cannot write `async function reportError(e: {fatal: true}): Promise<never>` because `Promise<never>` does not affect reachability the way we want... this is marked as a bug at [microsoft/TypeScript#34955](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34955).

---

On the other hand, when you call `reportError()` where `fatal` is not `true`, you want this to just be an asynchronous function which returns `void`... well, `Promise<void>`.  Like this:

```
async function reportError(e: { fatal?: false | undefined }): Promise<void>;
```

And we have to separate out the fatal and non-fatal cases into their own call signatures in order for reachability analysis to work how we want.  A single [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) call signature that returns a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) like `<E>(e: ReportableError) => E extends {fatal: true} ? never : Promise<void>` is conceptually the same, but is not treated like an assertion by the compiler.

---

Okay, so we have two call signatures and we need an implementation.  The full function looks like

```
function reportError(e: { fatal: true }): never;
async function reportError(e: { fatal?: false | undefined }): Promise<void>;
async function reportError(e: ReportableError) {
  if (e.fatal) {
    throw new Error("EXITING PROCESS OR SOMETHING");
  }
}
```

And let's see if it works how we want:

```
const result: Result | undefined = await getResult();
if (result === undefined) reportError({ fatal: true });
useResult(result) // okay
```

Great, `result` is narrowed.  And if we change the fatality level:

```
const result: Result | undefined = await getResult();
if (result === undefined) reportError({ fatal: false });
useResult(result) // error! undefined is not assignable to Result
```

Now `result` is not narrowed, and the compiler dislikes `useResult(result)` because `useResult()` does not accept `undefined`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEApeIA2AvJBvAsAFBJICWwALhAE4BmCyAStAK4YV5EkkgBcSUCtXIBzANxckAXyKTaLYPAqkA9sCQsoEZlDYUAFNVbt+OvQEp+ANxWkAJp2LTZT+YuVqkIiBTPt9lkgACtQqYKRaADx+HAA+GsB2ELTkEHYAfI7cSEYULNTqIWEREAB0RlAqGFYQ+gCyIBQAFuUgiWEBSJFIAAylAKxIAPx4SHxIAEQT0kj8CkkpwGnmkjKEkiBQAJ6KSG5Kquq0KiqdBE4k8GqCOcYUpndI8fPJqQ4AvGMA7iCkHN6+O4BCQXMi0JCGR7vaEJBZvcy3GAqagUACi1FC1H0uD2jUw-CELGQUnMIOymm0QIqFiQAHpaUgVABrEBbFwkNYbba7fYedQAIxAWIR52yV2AN2pJiQMSesNeSw+31+-x8MWBkhIpHBkN07CQ0M+L0Wy0RyLRGOR2NxFHxuIwWmkpM1Gi06qlFAR9KQNExAEJ5SaHBEkMAVBxNlBSCJQPyMMgKCoZXdVuyyJQaPREMmkSiQHGIOjMVluPRbRghgTqES5fQHchnokFWkydxvaUO6n1q4FAdPEZcxbMfoIPwcWW7YTiYEljVqK3Njt4Hte3yzSii1bR6MJxX+HXHY24YqnfwiuEojZ7OkF9zl7zDuuh1uHoP8-HN9QRS7tRCyrvv1BEhmlCL5QwgMDP30CZUQADQASQAFXggA5ABxYJGAAeQAYVRABlfCkCwxgkHwrC6lRRCAAlULQiZnVBNYORcIgpCAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
export async function reportError<E extends ReportableError>(
    e: E,
): E["fatal"] extends true ? never : Promise<Result | undefined> {
  // ...
}
```

See [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)

Comment: I don't want the `reportError` function to return the "result". I want to be able to type the fact that the function will exit the process if the `fatal` property is true or undefined, and continue running if the property is false.

Comment: @jackssrt you can use `never`. See updated answer.